# document.getElementById("id").value is working but $('#id).val is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input fields of text type. I am getting the values from a JSON object and trying to dynamically fill those values using javascript/jquery.
When I fill the values using `document.getElementById('id').value` it works fine. But `$('#id').val()` gives error.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label > First Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstName"> 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var UserID = 25;
function editUser(response)
{
   var obj = response;
   $.each(obj.userDataDTOList, function(index, item){
       if(item.userId == UserID)
       {
           document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value = item.userFirstname;
           //$('#txtFirstName').val() = item.userFirstname;
       }
   });
}
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
>           at Object. (editUser.js:35)
>           at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: The assignment is done like `.val(VALUE_TO_BE_SET)`. Whenever there is opening and closing braces, it means a function call. You don't call a function and set a value to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`.val()`**](https://api.jquery.com/val/) is a jQuery method that takes the value as parameter to set in the element.

Try

```
$('#txtFirstName').val(item.userFirstname);
```